# Retrieving font size from SharedPreferences to other activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

i am trying to retrieve the font size from the sharedpreferences from other activity. i already add the getPreferences method however it doesnt work. please explain to me i love knowledges.

as on the code, i succesfully changing the textsize using seekbar, and save it to sharedpreferences, however, in trying to retrieve the font size on other activity, it doesnt work.

here is my 1st activity java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class fontsize extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    //textsize

    int textSize = 30;

    //textView


    TextView textViewFont, textViewSize;

    //SharedPreferences

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;




    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fontsize);



        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        int progress = sharedPreferences.getInt("progress", 0);


        //definingtextview

        textViewFont = findViewById(R.id.textViewFont);
        textViewSize = findViewById(R.id.textViewSize);




        //seekbar



        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize+seekBar.getProgress()); // size 30sp

        textViewSize.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax()); // 0/30


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progressNew = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
                progressNew = progress;
                textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize);
                editor.putInt("progress", progress);
                editor.apply();



            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                textViewSize.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax()); // 0/30


            }
        });

        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout4);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view4);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(fontsize.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and my second activity java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class duatawassul extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    TextView textView;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duatawassul);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);




        textView = findViewById(R.id.duatawassultext);




        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout1);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view1);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(duatawassul.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(duatawassul.this, fontsize.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                finish();

        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your on create method in the second activity add the following which appears to be missing in your original code

```
   prefs = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);
   //this line is nowhere found in your second activity
   int progress=prefs.getInt("progress",0);
```

Comment: im sorry for the late reply as time differences between us, surely ill update answers check soon when i tried it thank you very much

Comment: i tried it, but it doesnt work. the size of the font on second activity still doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the share preferences in your app then you have to add value into the shared preference first like below keep in mind you can put it as a string and as an int, it's up to you that what you are using.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("fontsizeis", 14);
editor.apply();
```

After adding the values to the share preferences than you have to get the value. you can get the value from anywhere you wants for getting the value you can use this.

```
SharedPreferences sharePreferences= getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(sharePreferences.contains("fontsizeis")){
   int fontsizeis= sharePreferences.getInt("fontsizeis", 0); 
   if(fontsizeis != 0){
      Toast.makeText(context, "you find your desired value here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }else{
      Toast.makeText(context, "desired value not found some thing issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }    
}else{
   Toast.makeText(context, "Share preferences does not contain this key value pair", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

These conditions are use yo avoid the null point execption

Comment: im sorry for the late reply as time differences between us, surely ill update answers check soon when i tried it thank you very much